# Windows XP hour glass cursor?

Tags: windows-xp, images, extract, cursor

For an illustration, I need the Windows XP hour-glass cursor - with standard drop shadow - as a transparent image (PNG or whatever). Any idea?

I found a page with cursors, but the hour-glass one is missing:

http://telcontar.net/Misc/screeniecursors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've added the hourglass image to the collection.

**Note:** The %windir%\Cursors directory is not a solution because it lacks all the standard cursors -- small white arrow, small white hourglass, D&D copy, D&D move etc.

Answer (score 1):

The system cursors folder is in your windows directory;

```
C:\Windows\Cursors
```

You should be able to extract any frame from the image with a good image editting program. [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) will do this for you, for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, the drop shadow is missing from the cursor images. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: The drop shadow is added dynamically, so you will not find an icon file with it already in-place. You'll probably need to either keep taking screen-grabs (with a tool that includes the cursor in grabs) and hope to catch it at the right moment, or just use paint.net/GIMP/photoshop/what-ever to create the look manually.

Comment: I see. Edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I've been able to reproduce the drop shadow precisely in Adobe Photoshop 7 with the following parameters:

- **Colour:** black
- **Blend mode:** multiply
- **Opacity:** 32%
- **Angle:** 151–170°
- **Distance:** 3 px
- **Spread:** 0%
- **Size:** 3 px
- **Contour:** linear, non-antialiased